# Ubuntu 16.04 network auto disconnected but icon network still show connected

Tags: xubuntu

I have issue with network manager(Ethernet) .I can't connect to the internet seem the Ethernet auto disconnected sometimes.However network icon still show is connected.
I'm try reinstall network manager.But ethernet still not working.
Ubuntu 16.04
Please help me fix that.Thanks